# Devolver el valor de una funcion callback en el metodo createReadStream

Tags: callback

Apreciaria su ayuda con el siguiente problema: Tengo una funcion que descarga una imagen de mi s3 bucket. Quiero mandar la url de la imagen a mi servidor. Para ello, uso el metodo createReadStream. Este metodo tiene una funcion callback que me entrega un string con la url que quiero devolver. Mi problema es que no se como "extraer" ese valor para devolverlo y usarlo en mi servidor. Mi codigo se ve asi:

```
// services/wikiImage.js

download:async(imageKey)=>{
        
        const downloadParams={
            Key:imageKey,
            Bucket:bucketName
        }
         try {
         const imageFs=   await s3.getObject(downloadParams)
         const readImage=await imageFs.createReadStream(imageFs)
         
        readImage.on('data',(dataChunck)=>{
            console.log( dataChunck.toString()) //valor que quiero devolver
         }) 
         
         }
          catch (error) {
             console.log('this is the error',error)
         }
        
      
     }
```

Esta es la forma en que llamo esta funcion en mi servidor

```
//server.js
downloadImage:async(req,res)=>{
        const response=await wikiImage.download(req.params.key)
        res.send(response)
```

Mi objetivo es que res.send(response) sea igual a, por ejemplo la siguiente url:

//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Felipe_Calderon_20090130_%28cropped%29.jpg/220px-Felipe_Calderon_20090130_%28cropped%29.jpg

Es una imagen de wikipedia que tengo guardada en mi s3 bucket. He intentado devolver el valor del callback de varias formas sin exito.

Comment: En vez de crear un stream desde el backend, porque no devuelves la URL y que sea el frontend el que la acceda?

Comment: La razon es porque en el backend formo un arreglo de objetos. Cada objecto tiene imagen que saco de s3 bucket, y los demas datos(nombre, bio, twitt) los saco de mi base de datos. Entonces ese arreglo de objetos se forma dinamicamente desde mi servidor el query a mi base de datos lo realizo mediante un "nombre" que me llega del cliente. De esta manera ese mismo nombre es la llave de mi imagen en s3 bucket. Mi cliente debe recibir este arreglo de objetos y mediante el metodo array.map en react.js, renderizo cada objeto -perfil con imagen, nombre, bio y twitt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu método `download` devuelve el ReadableStream  en vez de procesarlo: (en realidad siendo una función asíncrona, devolverá una `Promise<ReadableStream>`)

```
     const imageFs=   await s3.getObject(downloadParams)
     return imageFs.createReadStream(imageFs)
```

En el handler puedes pipear ese readablestream a la respuesta de express, que es un writablestream.

```
downloadImage:async(req,res)=>{
    const readableStream=await wikiImage.download(req.params.key)
    readableStream.pipe(res)
}
```

Manejar un stream con otro stream es lo más sensato porque entre ellos administran el backpressure para una transferencia óptima, y se comunican los eventos de avance y de cierre que a uno se le pueden pasar por alto.

---

En los comentarios señalaste que quieres construir una respuesta combinando la salida del redablestream con otros datos. Para esto tendrás que recorrer el stream pero no debes asumir que vendrá en un solo chunk, sino concatenarlos hasta que el stream emita el evento `end`. Por ejemplo:

Tomado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428486/1030087

```
function streamToString (stream) {
  const chunks = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
    stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
  })
}
```

Y en este caso (donde notarás que no tengo idea de donde sale `otros_datos` pero eso sabrás obtenerlo tú)

```
downloadImage:async(req,res)=>{
    const readableStream=await wikiImage.download(req.params.key),
          resultado = await streamToString(readableStream)
    res.json({resultado,otros_datos, etc})
}
```

De todos modos, si un día S3 devuelve un binario y no un string, saldrá cualquier cosa en la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias. Use la segunda opcion que se ajusta a lo que estoy buscando con la app que estoy escribiendo. Muchas gracias.